# Umbraco: How to populate a ViewModel with IEnumerable IPublishedContent object?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco7

I feel this maybe straight forward but I have been struggling for hours.  I need to pass a list of items to a view model. The items are initially retrieved by using Umbraco's CurrentPage API.  This returns IPublishedContent object which requires a cast.  Could someone please advise how this would be achieved?

Model:

```
public class BlogsViewModel 
{
    public new  IEnumerable<BlogsViewModel> Blogs { get; set; }

    public new string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Listing(string category)
    {
        var model = new BlogsViewModel();
        
        var blogItems = CurrentPage.Children();
       
        model.Blogs = blogItems; //cast error here

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

I know I need to map to a list and then populate the view model but keep getting cast errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Library.ViewModels.BlogsViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```